# How do I test an instance variable in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

A couple of my mentors have told me to test a piece of code with controller spec even though the contents are being tested by some request specs. I am wondering if I can test whether an instance variable like `@user` can be set to `someObject` or `nil` from within an rspec controller test?

I've tried a couple different ways to test this so far, but my skills regarding rspec testing are to say the least, elementary. The first thing I tried was mocking out the current_user and the 'User.get_from_auth_user(current_user). The mocked object prints fine and outputs. The problem is... I want to be able to say something like `expect(@user).to equal(mockedUser)` but this never seems to work. I always get something like:

```
Expect does not equal received
expected is nil
received is { someMockedObject }
```

Here is the code I want to test.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user

  def set_user
    return if current_user.nil?

    @user = User.get_from_auth_user(current_user)
  end
end
```

I want to know if I'm going down the right path or what would be the better alternative to fully test this chunk of code. I feel like the answer should be a simple one.

Comment: Are you using factories and databaserewinder to create objects in db

Comment: @chans factories

Comment: The alternative that I went for was testing what 'set_user' returns. I did expect(controller.set_user).to eq(mockedUser)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your mentors are being stupid. While it can be good to understand controller specs as they are everywhere in legacy applications adding them to new applications is not a good practice.

> For new Rails apps: we don't recommend adding the
>   rails-controller-testing gem to your application. The official
>   recommendation of the Rails team and the RSpec core team is to write
>   request specs instead. Request specs allow you to focus on a single
>   controller action, but unlike controller tests involve the router, the
>   middleware stack, and both rack requests and responses. This adds
>   realism to the test that you are writing, and helps avoid many of the
>   issues that are common in controller specs.

DHH explains pretty well what is wrong with testing the instance variables of your controller and what you should be doing instead:

> Testing what instance variables are set by your controller is a bad
>   idea. That's grossly overstepping the boundaries of what the test
>   should know about. You can test what cookies are set, what HTTP code
>   is returned, how the view looks, or what mutations happened to the DB,
>   but testing the innards of the controller is just not a good idea.

Which is why `assigns` was extracted to a separate gem. It all boils down to testing what your code does - not how it does it.

See:

- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1838
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22496
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950

Comment: I don't really think your mentors are stupid. They are probably just out of touch with current best practices. If you want more concrete advice on how to write the test then I would ask a new question and describe the application behaviour you want to test instead.

Comment: The optimism in me says that this is just a learning exercise that his mentors gave him to better understand how RSpec/Rails work, especially considering that he already acknowledges that the tests aren't really doing anything useful because they are already covered by integration specs.

Comment: My mentor is definitely not stupid. I think they mostly want to help me get the idea of how to test and mock things. I do agree that controller specs should not be written as they are going away.

Comment: There are much better ways to teach that though. One key thing about mocking is that its crucial to understand when to mock and the drawbacks of mocking. The very problem with controller tests in the first place is that they mock too much of the system surrounding the controller which is why you can still get routing errors and other bugs that slip through.

Comment: "testing the innards of the controller is just not a good idea" -- why not? I don't see any substantiated argument here, just an opinion expressed vehemently.

Comment: Because it violates encapsulation. You're entitled to your opinion but  argument was settled a long time ago.

Comment: I completely disagree with the opinion that you shouldn't test instance variables.  Not testing instance variables is analogous to not testing a JSON response.  By just testing how the view looks, you would need to completely re-write all your view tests when the view changes even though it's displaying the same data.  Testing your instance variables can provide assurances that the same data is still available even though it may be displayed in a different format.

Comment: @MattMcCormick see the comment above. The discussion was settled eons ago. You're of course free to use controller tests and dig your head in the sand if you want to.

Comment: @MattMcCormick PS. If you want to have a contract between the controller and view you can do that with gems like [decent_exposure](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure) instead of relying on implicitly passing instance variables and using a testing method that is known to be extremely problematic and completely outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `assigns(:user)` to get the instance variable `@user`. In your spec, `@user` is a variable on that test context, it's not the same `@user` from the controller.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@chans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58403693/12201472) and [@arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58403588/12201472) answers, it worth to mention in order to use [`assigns`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/assigns) in your specs, you need to set up [`rails-controller-testing`](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) gem, because [`assigns`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/assigns) is deprecated starting from Rails 5.

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_process.rb, line 6
def assigns(key = nil)
  raise NoMethodError,
    "assigns has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it,
    add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller test case looks like this

```
describe 'GET #set_user' do
  let!(:mock_user) { 
      @mockuserObj = { id: 1, name: "username" }
  }
  before(:each) do
    controller.instance_variable_set(:current_user, @mockuserObj)
    get :set_user
  end
  context 'when current_user is present' do
    it "sets the current user" do
      expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(@mockuserObj)
    end
  end
end
```